# Matrix Multiplication of random numbers using rand() function

Tags: c, matrix-multiplication, dynamic-memory-allocation

Here is the code for matrix multiplication of random numbers using `rand()` function. The output of the program gives very large values as matrix elements.

> Why not any small random numbers not generated??

This is the output when N=3

Enter the value of N : 3

Final Matrix :

```
259448206-96933429-936226671  
-409898077185182340844598571  
-1916994436-653447116470937338
```

Program:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>

int main ()
{
    time_t t;
    int **ptr1, **ptr2, **ptr3;
    int N, col1, row2, col2;
    srand ((unsigned) time (&t));
    int i, j, k;
    printf ("\nEnter the value of N : ");
    scanf ("%d", &N);
    ptr1 = (int **) malloc (sizeof (int *) * N);
    ptr2 = (int **) malloc (sizeof (int *) * N);
    ptr3 = (int **) malloc (sizeof (int *) * N);

    for (i = 0; i < N; i++)
        ptr1[i] = (int *) malloc (sizeof (int) * N);
    for (i = 0; i < N; i++)
        ptr2[i] = (int *) malloc (sizeof (int) * N);
    for (i = 0; i < N; i++)
        ptr3[i] = (int *) malloc (sizeof (int) * N);

    for (i = 0; i < N; i++) {
        for (j = 0; j < N; j++) {
            ptr1[i][j] = rand ();
        }
    }

    for (i = 0; i < N; i++) {
        for (j = 0; j < N; j++) {
            ptr2[i][j] = rand ();
        }
    }

    for (i = 0; i < N; i++) {
        for (j = 0; j < N; j++) {
            ptr3[i][j] = 0;
            for (k = 0; k < N; k++)
                ptr3[i][j] = ptr3[i][j] + ptr1[i][k] * ptr2[k][j];
        }
    }

    /* Printing the contents of third matrix. */

    printf ("\n\nFinal Matrix :");
    for (i = 0; i < N; i++) {
        printf ("\n\t");
        for (j = 0; j < N; j++)
            printf ("%4d", ptr3[i][j]);
    }

    printf ("\n");
    return (0);
}
```

Comment: Have you checked how big `RAND_MAX` is?

Comment: Use the modulo operator to get smaller values (e.g. rand()%100). While it is slightly non-uniformly distributed that way this should not be an issue here.

Comment: `ptr3[i][j] + ptr1[i][k] * ptr2[k][j]` so readily overflows and `RAND_MAX` is likely large.  Use some delimiter like spaces `printf("  %4d", ptr3[i][j]);`

Comment: Given no control on the random numbers generated, I'd expect only 0.00046% of`ptr3[i][j]` to be less than 10,000 and code is only showing 9 of them.  Now if you had a  square matrix of 470x4700, you might have a 50% change of seeing a value < 10,000.

Comment: Also, do *NOT* cast the return of `malloc`. It is totally unnecessary and can hide errors. See: [**Do I cast the result of malloc?**](http://stackoverflow.com/q/605845/995714) for thorough explanation. (e.g. `ptr1[i] = malloc (sizeof *ptr1[i] * N);` is all you need.

Comment: I used rand()%100..and it solved the issue.. btw is there any way to set the value of RAND_MAX?? just curious.

Comment: To set the value of `RAND_MAX` would require a rebuild of portion of the STL like `rand()`, `srand()`. No easy way.  Using `rand()%n` is a reasonable alternative for learner programs.

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin The casts are indeed useful here to double-check the (intended vs. actual) types by the compiler. Quite a bad example for an unnecessary cast of malloc

Comment: To clarify on @chux comment: `RAND_MAX` is an implementation constant defined by your implementation of the standard library. As the name implies, it gives the max. value `rand` can yield. Getting larger values is problematic, but smaller values can be generated by various relatively simple algorithms, the most simple being modulus operation. Note this also has a bad distribution for divisors other than integer divisors of `RAND_MAX + 1`.

Comment: @chux – _a square matrix of 470x4700_? What a remarkable square! ;-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the modulo operator to get smaller values (e.g. rand()%100). While it is slightly non-uniformly distributed that way this should not be an issue here. – Ctx